# Using '&' notation in a directive used within an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to allow a directive with an isolate scope to call a function on it's parent directive's scope. I've read numerous examples of using '&' notation in the directive's scope declaration to do this, but since the directive is used inside an ng-repeat and an ng-switch, scope inheritance seems to be thwarting me. The function doesn't seem to make it to my directive's scope.

I can get to the function by going up the parent chain ($scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.removeElement() works), but that feels gross. Is there a way around this?

Parent Directive:

```
function dynamicLayoutDirective($compile, $log, bevoLayoutEngine, layoutService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'ECMA',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/dynamicLayout.html',
        scope: {
            layoutSchema: '=',
            layout: '=',
            editMode: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.removeElement = function(element) {
                // This is the function I want to call
            }
        }
    }
}
```

dynamicLayout.html

```
<div ng-repeat="element in layoutSchema">
    <div ng-switch on="element.type">
        <bevo-input ng-switch-when="TextBoxType" element="element" edit-mode="editMode" remove-element="removeElement"></bevo-input>
        <bevo-datepicker ng-switch-when="DateType" element="element" edit-mode="editMode"></bevo-datepicker>
        <bevo-section ng-switch-when="SectionType" element="element" edit-mode="editMode"></bevo-section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Child directive:

```
angular.module('ngBevoInput', []).directive('bevoInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/bevoInput.html',
        scope: {
            element: '=',
            editMode: '=',
            removeElement: '&'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.remove = function() {
                $scope.removeElement()({element: $scope.element});
                // $scope.removeElement() returns undefined here.
                // I can get to the function by doing $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.removeElement
            }
        }
    }
});
```

bevoInput.html

```
<div class="col-md-10 form-inline">
    <input type="text" value="{{element.display}}" ng-hide="editMode" />
    <input type="text" disabled ng-show="editMode" />
    <button ng-show="editMode" ng-click="remove()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 bugs that I can see:

1) You are assigning the callback function incorrectly.
You are only passing the function name, but Angular expects an expression that invokes an outer-scope function, so add the parenthesis and pass the `element` parameter.

```
<bevo-input remove-element="removeElement(element)"></bevo-input>
```

2) You are passing `{element: $scope.element}` to the return value of `$scope.removeElement` function. Remove the extra parenthesis.

```
$scope.removeElement({element: $scope.element});
```

**EDIT:**

Another issue I discovered has to do with the root element of the template having `ng-repeat` AND the template has `replace: true`. I'm not sure of the root cause (could be that the scope is lost), but to solve this, either (1) add another root, or (2) set `replace: false`.

Comment: Ah, I understand that part better now. However, in my child directive, removeElement() still evaluates to undefined within the remove function, and changing it to removeElement({element: $scope.element}) doesn't throw an error, but never invokes the parent directive's function. I've also noticed that anything that I attach to the parent directive's scope during the controller function ends up undefined if I try to pass it down to the child directive. Could this be the real problem?

Comment: There is another bug / typo. You are inadvertently passing element to the return value of `removeElement`. Updated the answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear. I tried the second step already, which resulted in no errors, but the parent directive function not being invoked.

Comment: Ah, I did miss that you found that bug. It [works for me](http://plnkr.co/edit/ar3UzDEc2GkPgQNVcPCx?p=preview) though (I had to mock a bit with your exact example since I don't have all the data, but without changing the nested nature of your template).

Comment: @BrianSullivan, Ok, so it looks there is an issue when the root element has `ng-repeat` and the directive has `replace: true`. Either adding a separate root or setting `replace: false` solves this.

Comment: @BrianSullivan, I was curious about this behavior, so I created another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609719/directive-with-root-element-with-ngrepeat-and-replace-true