# Directive with root element with ngRepeat and replace: true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Can someone explain the root cause behind the following behavior?

If a directive with isolate scope `scope: {}` has a root element with `ng-repeat` AND `replace: true` then it "breaks" the isolate scope, meaning that the isolate scope is not accessible/visible from within the directive, and the directive starts receiving variables from the outer scope.

Here's the minimally reproducible example I could make:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'MainCtrl';
});

app.directive("foo", function(){
  return {
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    template: "<div ng-repeat='item in [1]'>{{name}}</div>",
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.name = "foo";
    }
  };
});
```

The following view would render "MainCtrl":

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <foo></foo>
</div>
```

Adding either a non-`ng-repeat`-able root to the template OR setting `replace: false` renders the expected result "foo".

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V5VLw8lJOPslWAyGnDe0?p=preview)

Comment: I believe it is not just for ng-repeat, it could happen to anything that creates a child scope (eg: ng-if) and with replace true the child scope overwrites the isolated scope of the directive. Because i believe the replacement happens during the early compile phase.

Comment: This seems to be correct. Care to put this as a proper answer?

Comment: Apparently known bug: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9837

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not just happen for ng-repeat, this seems to happen for any other directives that creates a scope like `ng-if` as well.  And it seems like, this is because the directive's isolated scope gets overwritten by the ng-repeat's child scope. And because of `replace:true` option ng-repeat becomes a part of the directive source element i.e `<foo></foo>` and the child scope of ng-repeat is calculated from the ultimate parent scope `MainCtrl` (Which appears to be wrong) and this causes the entire directive template to be bound to the child scope of controller and any interpolations are evaluated against that scope. Hence you see main controller's scope being expanded in the directive. This seems like a bug.