# ng-repeat render order reversed by ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I've just come across this and am wondering if it's a bug or expected behaviour? This is just a small example to show the issue. The code below is used in both examples:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <item-directive ng-repeat="item in ::items" item="item"></item-directive>
</body>
```

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl)
    .directive('itemDirective', itemDirective)
    .factory('model', model);


function AppCtrl($scope, model) {

    $scope.items = model.getItems();
} 

function itemDirective() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            item: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'item-directive.html'
    };
}

function model() {

    return {
        getItems: getItems
    }

    function getItems() {

        return [
            {
                type: 'test',
                title: 'test 1'
            },
            {
                type: 'test',
                title: 'test 2'
            },
            {
                type: 'test',
                title: 'test 3'
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

The first example has this item-directive.html which gets rendered in the correct order as expected

```
<div>

    <span>{{::item.title}}</span>

</div>
```

[**Plunkr without ng-if**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FKofyWY0meJC7h40jcF3?p=preview)

But the second example - which has the below item-directive.html - incorporates an `ng-if`, which is causing the list to get rendered in reverse order?

```
<div ng-if="item.type == 'test'">

    <span>{{::item.title}}</span>

</div>
```

[**Plunkr with ng-if**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Enb7KZfwRJKwwhTYj6WN?p=preview)

-------- UPDATE ----------

I've just noticed (which relates to the issue noted in @squiroid's answer) that the isolate scope isn't actually working in this example. It appears to be, but `item` is being made available to the `item-directive` scope (or rather the scope it ends up with) by the `ng-repeat`, not the isolate scope. If you try to set any other values on the isolate scope, even though they show up on the scope passed to the directive's link and controller functions (as can be seen in the console output for the plnkr), they're not available to the template. Unless you remove `replace`.

[**Plunkr showing broken isolate scope**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Brw06D7sFmHIE5fYjg7Z?p=preview)

[**Plunkr showing fixed isolate scope when replace:false**](http://plnkr.co/edit/M0XlhqR9BqCUzhSwCDxh?p=preview)

--- UPDATE 2 ---

I've updated both of the examples to show the issue persisting once the the isolate scope is removed

[**Plunkr without ng-if and no isolate scope**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qG9zBzFg857NiOWBdDOI?p=preview)

[**Plunkr with ng-if and no isolate scope**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3AlGxz3YAvYbTURQ6nnW?p=preview)

And also a new version showing the change from templateUrl to template - as suggested by @Manube - that shows the behaviour working as expected

[**Plunkr with ng-if and no isolate scope using template instead of templateUrl**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ErWSV8IWBwVazF9aOt4d?p=preview)

Comment: First of all... LOL! Really interesting. Anyway, you should use a filter for that, not `ng-if` afaik.

Comment: yeah, i realised as i was writing it that there are probably better ways - i've ended up with an ng-include instead. But thought i'd see if anyone knew why this is happening as it seems pretty weird. I haven't used filters yet, i keep reading that they can be quite expensive? Can you supply a quick plnkr showing how you'd switch it to a filter please?

Comment: I don't know why it happens, but when you remove 'replace: true' in itemDirective, the order is no longer reversed!?

Comment: @Manube Well spotted

Comment: could it have to do with the way link functions work in reverse order, like detailed in this post: http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/ ? But there is no link function in itemDirective, just a templateUrl, so why?

Comment: Does it related to `$formatter.unshift` or `$parser.unshift`

Comment: Can anybody explain where I am wrong in my answer below ?

Comment: @james have you got any solution yet ?

Comment: This is a good question and is due to a bug in angular. I did some digging but couldn't reach the root cause. I'll continue tomorrow, and possibly open an issue on the GH repo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Directive with root element with ngRepeat and replace: true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609719/directive-with-root-element-with-ngrepeat-and-replace-true)

Comment: @NewDev please see my Update 2. I'd agree that the behaviour demonstrated in the Update 1 plnkrs, demonstrates the issue you've linked to. But the Update 2 plnkrs show that this has nothing to do with isolate scope directives.

Comment: @Mosho i did exactly that last night. Only to wake up to find it closed as i'd added it to the wrong (2.0) repo... It's now an issue on 1.x https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11131

Comment: Please check the `ngif` tag. It is not about the Angular directive: `NGif is an open-source tool that creates the ability for .Net to make/read Animated Gifs `.

Answer (score 1):

It is to do with templateUrl, which is asynchronous;

If you replace templateUrl by

```
 template:'<div ng-if="item.type === \'test\'"><span>{{::item.title}}</span></div>'
```

it will work as expected: [see plunker with template instead of templateUrl](http://plnkr.co/edit/z6yiFS1Bmo23elfGA3hC?p=preview)

---

the test `<div ng-if="item.type === 'test'">` will execute when scope is ready and the templateUrl has been fetched.

As the way the template is fetched is asynchronous, whichever template comes back first executes the test, and displays the item.

Now the question is: why is it always the last template that comes back first?

Comment: I know my answer is not perfect, but comments or, better, a more thorough explanation of the way templateUrl interacts with display, would certainly be more helpful than a plain downvote :)

Comment: The explanation is incorrect and it ends with a question.

Comment: There is only one request made for the template.

Answer (score 1):

### **Using ng-if on a root element of a directive with replace: true creates a broken scope**

[ISSUE](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9932)

This is happening with the combination of replace:'true' and ng-if on the root element.

Make sure the contents of your html in the templateUrl has exactly one root element.

If you place ng-if on span

```
<div >

    <span ng-if="item.type == 'test'">{{::item.title}}</span>

</div>
```

Now why it is happening,it is happening because  The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

which may lead to no root element on the templateUrl while rendering and thus leads to unwanted behaviour.

Comment: I guess this is the exact situation happening here can anybody let me know where i am wrong,So i can improve myself  :-)

Comment: @squiroid Good explaination +1 answer..I would have accepted your answer.. :)

Comment: Thanks @pankajparkar :-)

I dont know why i got -1 from someone :-)

Comment: @anonymous i am still waiting for your comment so that i can improve myself if i were wrong in this post.

Comment: It's incorrect. How does your answer explain why doing the exact same thing with `template` instead of `templateUrl` produces a different result?

Comment: template compile with directive while temlate url is async in nature so directive will delay until template url file is loaded.
Doc:-  "Because template loading is asynchronous the compiler will suspend compilation of directives on that element for later when the template has been resolved. In the meantime it will continue to compile and link sibling and parent elements as though this element had not contained any directives."

Comment: And how does that explain it?

Comment: No down voting on my part, i've just been having my dinner! I've read the link you posted and quite a few other related issues on the angular github, to get a better understanding of that issue. But i'm not sure why this would cause the list to be rendered backwards? As @Mosho pointed out, can you explain why it's not replicated when using `template` instead of `templateUrl`?

Answer (score 0):

second one showing in reverse order due to custom directive defined with item-directive name but its not rendering into DOM due to replace=true is used.

for more ref you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497706/angular-directive-replace-true)